# Задать маску при вводе c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Можно ли в c++ создать функцию которая бы задавала маску при вводе?: Н-р номера телефона.

```
"+7(***)***-**-**"
```

при вводе уже должна быть выведена маска строки, при нажатии на клавиатуру вместо звездочек должны появляться цифры.

Comment: Сделать-то можно все, что угодно :) Как? Ну, например, для каждого очередного вводимого символа проверять соответствие... Ваш вопрос настолько расплывчат, что на него практически нереально ответить :(

Comment: Вы имеете в виду ввод с консоли? И что в точности должно произойти, если юзер вводит неправильно?

Comment: @VladD, Да, при вводе уже должна быть выведена маска строки, при нажатии на клавиатуру вместо звездочек должны появляться цифры

Comment: @andy: Ого, тянет на хорошую фичу. Сомневаюсь, что такое возможно с использованием стандартной библиотеки. Придётся опуститься на уровень WinAPI и обрабатывать посимвольный ввод вручную.

Comment: @andy: Внесите лучше в вопрос, потому что текущий ответ немного про другое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такое у меня в винде получилось, работает с MinGW компилятором. Чисто демонстрация, дальше можете развивать как хотите уже.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int length = 0;
    int pospos = 0;
    int posarrays[10] = {3,4,5,7,8,9,11,12,14,15};
    int pos = posarrays[pospos];
    char mask[17] = "+7(***)***-**-**";
    printf("%s", mask);
    while(length != 10){
        int ch = getch();
        if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
            length++;
            mask[pos] = ch;
            system("cls");
            pospos++;
            pos = posarrays[pospos];
            printf("%s", mask);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Непосредственно при вводе (из консоли из стандартного потока) задать маску не получится. Но проверить номер телефона сразу после ввода можно используя регулярные выражения. Например:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() 
{
    std::string tel = "+7(495)123-45-67";
    std::regex rx("\\+([0-9]{1,3})(\\([0-9]{1,3}\\))([0-9\\-]{9})");
    std::cout << std::regex_match(tel, rx) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Собственно, в Windows можно использовать `getch()` и с ней можно непосредственно при вводе маску задать.

Comment: @ iksuy getch - собственно не имеет никакого отношения к Windows. Она (функция) читает по одному символу, не дожидаясь ввода. Но как Вы к ней собираетесь применить маску - ума не приложу. Приведите свой ответ с примером ее использования. Мне было бы очень интересно такое решение (с маской к getch).

Comment: Дополню @iksuy, на nix можно сэмулировать `getch()` при помощи `non-block read+select`

Comment: @MaxZS, читать символ и отправлять его в фильтр. Если выключить эхо ввода, то выводить на экран только после прохождения валидации, ровно как и запоминать в буффер ввода.

Comment: @Monah Tuk Да не дополняйте вы и не пишите в комментариях. Приводите готовые ответы, которые помогут топикастеру и последующим пользователям ресурса. И ответ был дан не минуту и не час назад. Он был дан тогда, когда вопрос топикастером был сформулирован несколько иначе.

Comment: Собственно выключения эха: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217908/how-to-disable-echo-in-windows-console (Windows) и http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=270335 (Linux, *nix)

Comment: @MaxZS у меня нет сейчас возможности дать развёрнутый ответ. И я не против, если кто-то возьмёт эти идеи и сделает полноценный ответ. Ну и не нужно ярости.

Comment: @Monah Tuk А никакой ярости и нет. Просто у Вас, похоже, и возможности читать чужие комментарии тоже нет. А иначе Вы бы прочитали комментарий VladD, данный часом ранее. Да и Вы с Вашей репутацией должны были бы уже знать, что никто комментарии не читает. А лично я не вижу разницы в возможностях между созданием комментариев и ответа. Можете даже просто их скопировать и вставить в ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с выключенным эхом и `getch()` для POSIX систем (для Windows будет полезна [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217908/how-to-disable-echo-in-windows-console))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void turn_off_input_echo();

#ifdef __linux
#include <termios.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

static termios s_savedAttributes = termios();

static void reset_input_mode()
{
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &s_savedAttributes);
}

void turn_off_input_echo()
{
    struct termios tattr;
    char *name;

    /* Make sure stdin is a terminal. */
    if (!isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Not a terminal.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Save the terminal attributes so we can restore them later. */
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &s_savedAttributes);
    atexit(reset_input_mode);

    /* Set the funny terminal modes. */
    tcgetattr (STDIN_FILENO, &tattr);
    tattr.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);  /* Clear ICANON and ECHO. */
    tattr.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tattr.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tcsetattr (STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &tattr);
}

int getch()
{
    fd_set rfds;

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &rfds);

    auto sts = select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &rfds, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (sts < 0)
        return -1;

    unsigned char ch;
    sts = read(STDIN_FILENO, &ch, sizeof(ch));
    if (sts == -1)
        return -1;

    return ch;
}

#elif defined(__WIN32)
#error Implement turn_off_input_echo()
#endif

class ProcessInputPattern
{
public:
    ProcessInputPattern(const string& pattern)
        : m_pattern(pattern)
    {
    }

    virtual ~ProcessInputPattern() = default;

    bool processInput()
    {
        init();
        redraw();
        while (true)
        {
            auto ch = getch();
            switch (ch) 
            {
                case EOF:
                case '\n':
                    cout << endl;
                    return m_pos == m_count;
                case 127:
                case 8:
                    if (m_pos > 0)
                        --m_pos;
                    redraw();
                    break;
                default:
                    if (doValidate(static_cast<char>(ch)))
                    {
                        if (m_pos < m_count)
                        {
                            m_input[m_pos++] = ch;
                            redraw();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    string getFilledPattern() const
    {
        string pattern = m_pattern;
        if (m_pos)
        {
            size_t idx = 0;
            for (auto& ch : pattern)
            {
                if (isPlaceholder(ch) && idx < m_pos)
                {
                    ch = m_input[idx++];
                }
            }
        }
        return pattern;
    }

    string getInputData() const
    {
        string data;
        if (!m_pos)
            return data;
        data.resize(m_pos);
        for (size_t idx = 0; idx < m_pos; ++idx)
            data[idx] = m_input[idx];
        return data;
    }

    size_t currentPos() const
    {
        return m_pos;
    }

    size_t placeholdersCount() const
    {
        return m_count;
    }

    bool completeLine() const
    {
        return m_count == m_pos;
    }

protected:
    void init()
    {
        m_pos = 0;
        m_count = 0;

        for (auto ch : m_pattern)
        {
            if (isPlaceholder(ch))
                ++m_count;
        }

        m_input.resize(m_count);
    }

    void redraw() const
    {
        cout << '\r' << getFilledPattern() << flush;
    }

    virtual bool doValidate(char ch) const
    {
        return ch >= '0' && ch <= '9';
    }

    virtual bool isPlaceholder(char ch) const
    {
        return ch == '*';
    }

private:
    string       m_pattern;
    vector<char> m_input;
    size_t       m_count = 0;
    size_t       m_pos   = 0;
};

int main()
{
    turn_off_input_echo();

    ProcessInputPattern inp("+7(***)***-**-**");

    auto sts = inp.processInput();

    if (sts)
        cout << "complete line: " << inp.getFilledPattern() << " / " << inp.getInputData() << endl;
    else
        cout << "partial line: " << inp.getFilledPattern() << " / " << inp.getInputData() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод может выглядеть примерно так:

```
$ ./a.out 
+7(436)365-37-78
complete line: +7(436)365-37-78 / 4363653778

$ ./a.out 
+7(444)***-**-**
partial line: +7(444)***-**-** / 444
```

Решение призвано показать идею. Конкретную реализацию делайте на свой усмотрение. Возможно, лучшим вариантом будет рассмотреть библиотеки типа ncurses или S-Lang для управления терминалом или их аналоги для Windows (конкретики не подскажу).

Comment: Регуляркой как-то проще будет :)

Comment: а я не утверждал, что проще :) Во всяких библиотеках для TUI такое скрыто (или подобное) в недрах реализации. Поэтому, если нужен сложный экранный ввод, лучше использовать какие-то более подходящие инструменты.