# C++ unbuffered I/O interruptions

Tags: c++

Допустим, у меня есть программа, которая бесконечно выводит что-то в консоль(например, время после ее запуска). Но мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии определенных клавиш действие программы прерывалось и выполнялись нужные действия для данной клавиши. Пишется под ubuntu. Трудность в том, что getch(), к примеру, ждет ввода, а мне нужно, чтобы все это время программа продолжала выполняться. Кроме того, какие существуют средства для небуферизированного ввода-вывода в стандартной библиотеке?

Comment: Смотрите лучше в сторону ncurses или slang

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717572/how-do-you-do-non-blocking-console-i-o-on-linux-in-c

Comment: `kbhit` должен подойти

Comment: Вы собираетесь опрашивать время от времени ввод с  консоли или хотите асинхронного оповещения? / И второе уточнение -- реагировать на каждое нажатие или предполагается ввод строк по <Enter>? (@Qwertiy, по крайней мере стандартно(?) в Ubuntu нет `kbhit`)

Comment: @avp, `kbhit` и `getch` оба из нестандартного `conio.h` - полагаю, наличие `getch` (упоминаемого в вопросе) означает и наличие `kbhit`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, возможно. Я всегда использовал стандартные tcgetattr/tcsetattr из termio.h и fgetc (или что лучше по алгоритму задачки подходит)

Comment: @Qwertiy Где ТС нашел getch() это конечно большой вопрос, ибо ни conio.h ни getch() ни kbhit() в linux нет

Comment: @Mike а я вот [нашел](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) за минуту гугления :)

Comment: @Qwertiy вообще-то, `getch`  есть не только в `conio.h`

Comment: @PavelMayorov А смотреть в сторону curses я предлагал еще в самом первом комментарии к вопросу :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, о, "if no input is waiting, the value ERR is returned" :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я же исправил комментарии. Я сначала ссылку не заметил, потом не туда посмотрел :)

Answer (score 2):

Вам дорога в асинхронность. Попробуйте libev. В частности опрос клавиатуры сделайте через него же:

1. выключить echo
2. сделать fd `STDIN_FILENO` неблокирующим
3. повесить обработчик события на цикл libev

Если хочется костыльного. То можно сделать только пункты 1 и 2, в результате, если ввод с клавиатуры (при помощи `read(STDIN_FILENO, ch, sizeof(char));`) не готов, то будет возвращено -1 и `errno` выставлено в EWOULDBLOCK.

Естественно libev можно заменить:

1. libevent
2. libuv
3. Asio
4. своим решением на select/poll/epoll/kqueue/etc

Выключение echo в консоли гуглится на раз два. Можно, к примеру, посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509930/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-c/510141#510141).

Про atexit: https://manned.org/atexit.3. Если коротко: в примере выше используется, что бы восстановить состояние терминала по выходу из приложения и дабы не забыть это сделать вручную.

Comment: Про `atexit(reset_input_mode);` упомяните, а то ведь не сразу докопается

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - обрабатывайте комбинацию клавиш Ctrl + C. Это делается обработкой сигнала SIGINT. Вот тут есть пример кода: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17766999